# How could we pass collection parameters to an APEX controller method in lightning

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-connect, lightning

Could someone tell me how could we pass collection parameters to an APEX controller method in lightning;

In the below code;

saveAccountDetails is my Aura enable Apex method,

I'm setting accountIds array as a parameter value for accountIds parameter.

My question is how could I get the list of String values pushed through lightning component to an Apex String array?

HELPER.js function

```
updateAccountDetails : function(cmp, ev,helper) {
    // calling the server controller method to final save
    var action = cmp.get("c.saveAccountDetails");

    var accountIds = new Array("0011900000Cypyq", "0011900000Cypyt", "0011900000Cypyr");
    action.setParams({ "accountIds": accountIds });

    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        try {
            self.actionResponseHandler(response, cmp, self, self.gotAccount);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('Exception ' + e);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

APEX Controller method

```
@AuraEnabled
global static void saveAccountDetails(List<String> accountIds) {
    system.debug(accountIds);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting any error ? or is it just not being passed ? in your apex method your parameter is accountIds, but in your debug statement its userIds.

Comment: This is a known bug. Currently AuraEnabled functions do not take collection or wrapper class as input param. Also it does not return wrapper class as output.

Comment: @Vimasi, yes it should be accountIds and I re-correct the typo which happened while I was writing the post, apologies for that!

Answer (score 1):

If you passing a correct type of parameter to an apex method, it will work with Lightning similar to JS Remoting.

You can even create an Account JS Variable and pass it to Apex

```
var Account ={
FirstName ='abc';
LastName ='abc';
CustomField__c ='pwq'; //proper values
}
```

For complex scenarios, I would recommend to pass a JSON string and resolve it back in Apex method.

```
@AuraEnabled
global static void saveAccountDetails(String jsonString) {
    List<MyComplexStructure>  = accountsJSON.deSerialize(jsonString,Class.MyComplexStructure);
} 

Class MyComplexStructure{
    Integer a;
    List<String> myStringList;
    String token;
    .....

}
```

> Note : Your variables name in JSON String should match to structure class variables.