# Lightning Components: Which type of parameters are supported in @AuraEnabled Apex methods?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Assume we have this code in the controller or helper to invoke a APEX method:

```
action = cmp.get("c.TestUwe");
action.setParams( { params :  ['777','888'] } );
action.setCallback( null, function(callbackResult) {
    if(callbackResult.getState()=='SUCCESS') {
        var result = callbackResult.getReturnValue();
        console.log('RESULT', result  );
    }
    if(callbackResult.getState()=='ERROR') {
        console.log('ERROR', callbackResult.getError() ); 
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction( action );
```

In Apex we have one input param of `List<Object>`:

```
@AuraEnabled public static Object TestUwe(List<Object> params) {
    system.debug( params );
    return null;
}
```

**All good: this works fine!**

Now if I change the type to just `Object`

```
@AuraEnabled public static Object TestUwe(Object params)
```

It does not work anymore:

> An internal server error has occurred↵Error ID: 1556564141-71620
>   (-2109904195)↵↵org.auraframework.throwable.AuraExecutionException:
>   apex://elfLC_WorkOrderLineItemEditor:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException↵  at ...

Other example is: we keep `List<Object>` in APEX but provide this as `params`:

```
action.setParams( { params :  ['777','888', { test : 'abc' }] } );
```

> An internal server error has occurred↵Error ID: 1556564141-71801
>   (119852647)↵↵org.auraframework.throwable.AuraExecutionException:
>   apex://elfLC_WorkOrderLineItemEditor:
>   common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Salesforce System Error:
>   1556564141-71800 (-1664928234) (-1664928234)↵ at ...

**So not *all* possible types works as expected.**

I've read these [chapters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm) but can't find any documentation on which types are supported and which not. Where does Salesforce specify EXACTLY what is allowed and what not?

I found some posts where people serialize the parameters, e.g.:

- [How could we pass collection parameters to an APEX controller method in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101723/how-could-we-pass-collection-parameters-to-an-apex-controller-method-in-lightnin)
- [How to pass sobject list to apex from lightning?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147632/how-to-pass-sobject-list-to-apex-from-lightning)
- https://blog.texei.com/lightning-components-auraenabled-method-parameters-whats-working-and-what-s-not-83c351356104

Why is this necessary at all? Why can't the framework just do the serialization of anything on it's own and in APEX we just use the typeless `Object` and take care on proper handling from there dynamically?

But the main question is:

**Where do I find the official documentation on which types are allowed and which are forbidden?** It should be stated at a prominent place [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm) in order to save us a lot of trial-and-error time.

Comment: Interested to see if you get an official answer on this. Nothing except string seems to work reliably, see also this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108355/limit-expression-must-be-of-type-integer-error-when-using-apex-variable-in-soq

Comment: @Aidan missing docs on this would by very bad, because it's  wasting a lot of developers time for nothing... I always think: it's me not reading the right place....

Comment: I'd assumed that they meant the parameter types to work the same way as the return types, which they list here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm But, as in by previous link, Integers don't work correctly. And I've found that collections of collections don't work right as a return value.

Comment: I cant check it now but will propose to try for: { params :  ['777','888'] }  -  Map<String, List<string>>

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the best practice for passing parameter from Lightning component to Apex class is to use `JSON.stringify()` on anything that is more complicated than single string (every list, map, object, map of lists, ...). You can then deserialize/parse it in apex, which is safer then managing it in javascript.