# Unable to pass more than 32 parameters in a method

Tags: apex

Since I know the limit is 32 parameters can be pass to a method, but I have a requirement where I need to pass more than it in a @httppostmethod. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

You can take either of these approaches:

- Define an Apex class and pass a reference to that as a single parameter (as described e.g. here [How to pass an object from a Lightning Component helper to an Apex Controller method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216176/how-to-pass-an-object-from-a-lightning-component-helper-to-an-apex-controller-me)). The properties need to be e.g. `@AuraEnabled String myProperty {get; set;}` for the deserialisation to work.
- Do the deserialisation yourself straight out of the [RestContext Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restcontext.htm). This is a good approach if the content will change over time or vary per request.